# Two 'for' loops at once in python

Tags: python, list

Say I'm iterating through a list in python:

```
lines = [1, 2, 3, 4]

linecount = len(lines)

#I want to be able to do this:
for i, j in range(linecount - 1, -1, -1), range(linecount, -1, -1):
    print i, j

"""
This would print out
3 4
2 3
1 2
0 1
0 0
"""
```

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i, j in zip(range(linecount - 1, -1, -1), range(linecount, -1, -1)):
    print i, j
```

Comment: Note, though, that `zip` truncates to the shortest sequence, so you don't get a final `0, 0` pair.  See, e.g., `itertools.izip_longest` for a way to go with the longest sequence.